# Check boxes in IE not being displayed correctly

Tags: css, checkbox, internet-explorer-9

When viewing my site http://www.styleiq.co.uk the check boxes are styled correctly and function as required when using Chrome.

When using IE (IE9) the first category of check boxes is displayed correctly but any others that follow revert to default styling. I don't see what could be causing this as the css classes and layout are the same.

If anybody is able to help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have a JavaScript error that might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin in the comments is exactly right.

In modern browsers (except for IE9 and older) JavaScript will usually continue to run after an error is thrown. In old IE, no JavaScript is processed following an error.

The styling is applied by the JavaScript everywhere except old IE. When you resolve the JavaScript error, the script will finish executing and the style/replacement will be applied.

The error that's thrown is `'length' is null or not an object`.

The only JavaScript error I can see with respect to `length` is inline in your homepage on line 7405:

`if ($("#grid-content").length = 0){`

You need two `==` to make a comparison, here you are using just one.

But, it's hard to tell without truly debugging your code, whether this is the source of the problem or not. The error that's thrown is in jQuery's source, here:

```
each: function( object, callback, args ) {
    var name, i = 0,
        length = object.length, ## THIS length is throwing the error
        isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( object );
```

Comment: I have made the amend to if ($("#grid-content").length = 0){ but still no joy.

Comment: I think the error is elsewhere, somewhere in the script it's trying to `.each()` a non-group. I can try to debug...

Comment: Set Sail Media, are you able to contact me on aleej123@googlemail.com to help me debug? I can pay a small fee if that helps :)